# Creating an XML file in android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xml-serialization

Hi is there an equivalent  for C#'s XML serialization for android? kind of stuck with it couldn't really find a solution for it

Comment: Is this native Android Java or C# Mono for Android? If the latter, I'm pretty sure the basic `XmlSerializer` and associated classes still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: for XML writing I recommend 3rd party, relatively small library [XML Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

You can probably utilize [XmlDocumentProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/xmladapters/XmlDocumentProvider.java) in Android examples that you can find in your Android distro in /android-sdk/samples/android-16/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/XmlDocumentProvider.java

According to JavaDocs it is

> A read-only content provider which extracts data out of an XML
>   document.

You will use it as a regular content provider (read only) so you can query, filter etc. and get a cursor that you can use in things like CursorAdapter